# Javascript: Append string in specific offset position of an input

Tags: javascript, string, input, offset

Is there a way to append a string in a specific offset position  on an input? Suppose we have the following input : 
an offset  : `<input type="text" value="abcdef"/>`, the letter c is situated in the 3th offset of the input string value.

+-------------+
 123456789                 
 +-------------+ 
 xxxxxxx->offset position

Let's say I want to append the string "hi" in the 3th poistion of the input so it become :

+-------------+
    hi                 
 +-------------+ 
123456789

How can I do that?

thanks.

Comment: what is an offset for you ? a line, a character ? I don't understand what you want

Comment: an example : <input type="text" value="abcdef"/>, the letter c is situated in the 3th offset of the input string value ..

Comment: Never mind, i found a solution to my problem.. thanks

Comment: please post your answer for others and mark it as valid in two days.

Comment: -1 for question inclarity. Appending is the act of adding something to the end of something else. **Inserting** is the act of putting something in the middle of something else.

Comment: thanks for this clarification;)! by the way i'm trying my best to write english, do you think that all SOF members are english ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could very easily write your own function to do that.

```
function insertAt(src, index, str) {
    return src.substr(0, index) + str + src.substr(index)
}
alert(insertAt("test", 2, "FOO")); //Alerts teFOOst
```